# How to pass custom list in affolstad material dialog for multi selection?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

Below is my code,

```
 val dataList = MutableList<Data> = mutableListOf()
MaterialDialog(requireContext()).show {
    customView(view = multiSelectDataSearchBinding.root)
    title(R.string.search_by_name)
    listItemsMultiChoice(null,dataList,waitForPositiveButton = false) { dialog, index, text ->
  
    }

    positiveButton(R.string.done_label) {
       
    }
    cornerRadius(res = R.dimen.cu_scale_16dp)
}
```

How to pass custom arraylist in affolstad material dialog? It only accepts string array. Is there any way to pass custom arraylist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can pass custom list to afollestad's Material Dialogs.

As this library gives you functionality to use custom views, you can definitely create a custom layout and add multi-selection logic onto that view, and then add that custom view to Material Dialog.

To add a custom layout, use the below code:

```
val dialog = MaterialDialog(this, dialogBehavior).show {
  title(R.string.multi_selection)
  customView(R.layout.custom_view, scrollable = true, horizontalPadding = true)
  positiveButton(R.string.connect) { dialog ->
    // Pull the list out of the custom view when the positive button is pressed
  }
  negativeButton(android.R.string.cancel)
  lifecycleOwner(this@MainActivity)
}
```

For the logic about multi-selection, [read this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-selection-support-to-a-recyclerview--cms-32175#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20Add%20Multiple%20Selection%20to%20Android,Touches.%20For%20the%20RecyclerView%20Selection%20addon...%20More%20).

Comment: No, I think you don't get my question. I want to pass custom list inside  listItemsMultiChoice function. Currently we can only pass string array inside this.

Comment: Then You can use it's custom adapter method there is already given custom adapter method in this library.

Comment: Yes I knew that's an only solution for that. this lib doesn't support for custom list